# UITextView textContainer exclusion path not working when it's middle of view controller

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, uibezierpath

I have my UIView in the middle of the View Controller and I am setting the exclusion path as follow

```
    -(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
    {
      UIBezierPath *exludedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:aRect];
      self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[excludedPath];
    }
```

here aRect has same x and y as UITextView and reasonable height and width

this code does work when my UITextView is at the top of the view controller but doesn't when it's somewhere in the middle of the view controller.

Is it the viewController life time issue? or some property of the view controller that's causing this?

Comment: To help answer this you should provide debug values for `aRect` and `textView.frame`. Can you provide image showing text flow that is not correct? A minor point: `textView` is inside a parent UIView not a UIViewController. A UIViewController is not a visible object. It has no dimensions in the layout, so nothing can be in the middle of it.

Comment: A quick thing to try: because `NSTextContainer` is about layout maybe move your code to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` instead. Layout should be done by the time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called. Perhaps when `textView` is at the top of its parent view, it only looks right because of coincidence but your code is never having an effect because it is called after view layout is over.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your exclusionPath's rect, and make sure it's really included in textViewContainer.size; I'm confronted by a similar bug, and at last I fixed it by checking.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking at this question, I had the same issue and figured out that the rect was incorrect. Say your image view's rect is (20, 30, 50, 50) and the text view's rect is (20, 30, 300, 400). The bezier path's rect should be (0,0,50,50), not (20, 30, 50, 50). That is, pass the bounds and not the actual frame.